# Windows Server 2022 DataCenter at Version 15 of PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, windows, postgresql-15

I am new to PostgreSQL so forgive me for asking, but I see that on https://www.postgresql.org/download/windows/ Version 15 shows 2019,2016 being supported Windows Platforms. Is it safe to assume Windows Server 2022 would work or should I generally stick to what they list on that webpage?

Then follow up questions:

- Is there another good resource to find an answer to this question that you would use?
- When would a new version for PostgreSQL come out that might support Windows Server 2022?

thanks

Searched documentation and google searches did not provide the answer.

Comment: I think that list simply means no one has _tested_ on that platform. I would be surprised, it it didn't run on Windows Server 2022. But Postgres runs much better on Linux anyway. And many important tools and extensions don't work on Windows, so that's another reason to not run a production Postgres server with Windows.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.